# Tomee+ JAX-RS: Jackson annotations ignored

Tags: annotations, cxf, jackson, apache-tomee

I've got a problem with Jackson annotations that seem to be ignored in Tomee+ v1.
I use Jackson to have my REST responses serialized to JSON. I switched it on setting:
**openejb.cxf.jax-rs.providers = org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider**
in system.properties

Jackson serialization works fine except all Jackson annotations that seem to be completely ignored. Event the basic ones like @JsonIgnore or @JsonProperty have no effect on the json response. I also tried Mix-ins but they don't work either.

I tried with Jackson 1.X and Jackson 2.x.

The only thing that affects JSON structure is Jaxb annotations(like @XmlTransient).

Anyone have it working in Tomee+???
Any feedback much appreciated

Cheers,
qmacpit

Answer (score 1):

It turned out it didn't work properly in TomEE+ v 1.0.
If you'd like to have it running you've got to use the later version(currently it is the snapshot one).
Check out my original thread at official tomEE forum.
http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/TomEE-Jackson-ignored-annotations-td4657511.html#a4657518